# Миграция пользователей с FileZilla на ProFTPd?

Tags: mysql, хеширование, md5, миграция, ftp-сервер

Здравствуйте, уважаемые профессионалы ! 
У нас тут проект по реорганизации инфраструктуры компании. Мне поручено ввести в строй новый файловый сервер на Линукс, взамен прежней FileZilla. Остановился на proftpd.

Задача: автоматизированная миграция 600+ аккаунтов с мэппингом их папок и, главное, паролей.

Пробовал proftpd+MySQL, несколько вариантов proftpd с виртуальными пользователями. Пока ничего.

FZ хранит аккаунты в XML-файле, пароли захэшированы посредством MD5 и без соли. Proftpd сохраняет MD5 с солью в файл конфигурации. Не осознаю, как их слить.

Может, кто знает, хоть в каком направлении искать дальше? Спасибо за советы!

Comment: Никак. Пусть новые пароли заводят. Хе-хе. И вообще пора бы научиться жить по новому. Пользователи не в какой-то MySQL, а в Active Directory. А сервисы, которые не понимают AD, удалять с последующим форматированием диска.

Comment: не, ну я только за =) но тут проблема в том, что пользователи в основном сторонние клиенты фирмы со всего мира.

Comment: Их туда же. Есть же какие-то варианты чтобы и чужаков в AD держать